# Hamburger Menu Positioned in Bottom Footer, not centered

Tags: center, footer, hamburger-menu

I have a project I'm working on that's here (www.theivyproject.com/designlab001)
I have a hamburger menu for the footer, once the menu appears, the hamburger is not centered, it's aligned to the left.  How can I center this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adjusting the width of the nav class menu from 50px to 30px.  This seemed to get rid of the weird positioning of the hamburger as well as help align the elements for the menu a little better.